# Why does Eclipse ask me to 'ant build' every time I try to run my Python program?

Tags: python, eclipse, build, ant, pydev

I am new to programing and using pydev to run my python in eclipse.  I am using Eclipse EE and Python 2.7.3  The code I am trying to run is here:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):

        sumPoly = 0

        for i in range(0,len(poly)):
            #calculate each term and add to sum.
            sumPoly = sumPoly+(poly[i]*x**i)
        return sumPoly




def compute_deriv(poly):

    derivTerm = ()

    #create a new tuple by adding a new term each iteration, assign to derivTerm each time.
    for i in range(0,len(poly)):
    #i is the exponent, poly[i] is the coefficient,
    #coefficient of the derivative is the product of the two.
        derivTerm = derivTerm + (poly[i]*i,)
    return derivTerm



def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon):

    #define root to make code simpler.
    root = evaluate_poly(poly,x_0)
    iterations = 0

    #until root (evaluate_poly) is within our error range of 0...
    while (root > epsilon) or (root < -epsilon):
    #...apply newton's method, calculate new root, and count iterations.
        x_0 = (x_0 - ((root)/(evaluate_poly(compute_deriv(poly),x_0))))
        root = evaluate_poly(poly,x_0)
        iterations = iterations + 1
    return (x_0,iterations)

print compute_root((4.0,3.0,2.0),0.1,0.0001)
```

Every time I try to run this eclipse asks me to ant build.  When I click ok nothing happens. This only happens when I run functions inside functions it seems very basic code isn't an issue.  What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: This is a generic annoyance with Eclipse, and there's no need to show your code, it's not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is functions, python isn't going to do anything. It's not going to just run arbitrary functions for no reason. If you want something to be printed out you need to call one of your functions. The best way is to add this to the bottom of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    evaluate_poly([1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Nathan.  I just edited the code because I saw that I was using print in my first two functions not return.  I added a print statement at the end to print the last function.  This worked when I was only using one function however my code is still asking me to ant build.

Comment: @Nathan: yes, but that was not the underlying issue being asked about though, about Eclipse always trying to do 'ant build' on arbitrary Python (or other) code.